# What is a Fatal error actually?

Tags: fatal-error

I wonder what Fatal error means. Why do they happen? Why do we see them in so much places? I saw them so many times, In Node.js, CS:GO and many places but why do they happen? A logical error or something in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A fatal error is an error that causes a program to terminate without
>   any warning or saving its state. A fatal error, upon occurring, aborts
>   the application currently running, and may cause the user to lose any
>   unsaved changes made in the program. Exact reasons for fatal errors
>   are very difficult to determine.
>
> A fatal error occurs when an application tries to access invalid data
>   or code, an illegal action is attempted or an infinity condition is
>   met. The program shuts down and returns the user to the operating
>   system. An operating system keeps a log of the information related to
>   the error for the user to view the details and determine possible
>   causes of the fatal error. Similarly, in some cases the image of a
>   process (core dump) is also sometimes maintained by the OS in the
>   event of a fatal error.